# why has error equal with int in sql server 2008

Tags: sql

when i write the sql in 2008:

declare @recieved int

```
    --find the isJieShou int
    select @recieved=isJieShou
    from Prj_SignF
    where Row_Guid=
    (
        select Row_Guid
        from prj_specTechInterface
        where intfaceID=@specTechInterface
    )


    if(@recieved==1)
    --begin
    --end
```

It hint that `if(@recieved==1)`    `=` have a syntax error?

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your RDBMS but your problem is mostlikely because equality is done using single `=`

```
if(@recieved=1)
```